How to calculate standard deviation when only mean of the data, sample size, and t-test is available?
I found a study that reports the following data for two groups:
Mean (7.5 and 8.68)
Sample size of each group (26 and 22)
P-value from the independent one-tailed t-test (0.055)
Is there a formula to calculate the standard deviation?

oops -- did you really mean the one-tailed test? Which direction?

First we back-calculate the $t$-statistic from the $p$-value using the quantile function of the $t$ distribution: dividing $p$-value by 2 for two-tailed test, degrees of freedom for the two-sample $t$-test is $n_1+n_2-2$ ... in R,
t_stat <- qt(0.055/2, df = (26+22-2)) ## -1.968953

(I note that the OP says they did a one-tailed test: if this is really the case, don't divide by 2 ...)

there's no simple closed-form formula for qt(); in the old days you'd have to look things up in tables and interpolate ... but this function should be available in most numerical programming languages (R, Python, Matlab, ...)
sanity check: this value is close to the well-known Normal 95% cutoff of 1.96, which makes sense since the df is relatively large and the p-value is close to 0.05.

Now (from Wikipedia) in the equal-variance case we have
$$
t = \frac{x_1-x_2}{\sigma_p \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2}}}
$$
so
$$
\sigma_p = \frac{\Delta x}{t  \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2}}}
$$
abs((7.5 - 8.68)/(t_stat*sqrt(1/26 + 1/22)))  ## 2.068826

